# Can't run project - Android Studio 2.0 Crashlytics issues

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I updated Android Studio to 2.0 and trying to get instant run to work.
Gradle sync works. 
Rebuilding the project works.
Trying to run, fails :(.

What am I doing wrong?

Variables:

- io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.14.4
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1
- buildToolsVersion 23.0.2

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':Application:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug'. 
Task with path 'dexDebug' not found in project ':Application'. 
Try:Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':Application:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:53)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.realizedDependencies(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:181)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:138)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:76)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with path 'dexDebug' not found in project ':Application'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.getByPath(DefaultTaskContainer.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.resolveTask(DefaultTaskContainer.java:161)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.resolve(DefaultTaskDependency.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:63)
        ... 51 more
```

Comment: I have the same issue and none of solutions work for me! (android studio 2.2, gradle:2.2.0)

Comment: @HamedGh did you managed to fix this? I'm using AS 2.2 gradle:2.2.0 and fabric:1.21.5 and it's working just fine

Comment: @Andrei_Verdes Unfortunately, no, I asked another question, plz look at that and if you could answer my question: [Can't release the project using crashlytic after upgrading to java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674118/cant-release-the-project-using-crashlytic-after-upgrading-to-java-8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and tried many thing without success.
The only solution I found was to delete all references to fabric or crashlytics from any gradle file (substantially from the repositories and the compile sections) and then re-adding them through the fabric plugin.

I suppose that there were some duplicated and incompatible inclusions.

Fore example I had (some of the following lines where in the project gradle and others were in the module gradle)

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.16.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.0'
}
```

Now I've only

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.0'
}
```

Comment: How would deleting the references and re-adding them trough the the Fabric plugin fix this? The plugin just re-writes the references we just deleted...and also it doesn't work

Comment: I suppose there where some mixed inclusions from crashlytics and from parse. Removing and readding was just a way to remove old references and adding only the needed ones.
I edited my answer (it was too long to reply here)

Comment: Yey! Updating io.fabric.tools:gradle to 1.20.0 did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just updated to Android Studio 2.0, I encounter the same issue. My solution was changing the plugin version to the latest, `1.21.5`. The plugin's repository url is https://maven.fabric.io/public, but I got the latest version from [here](https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/repo/io/fabric/tools/gradle/).

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that if you change the  io.fabric.tools:gradle to this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.1'
}
```

It will work again.

I'm using Android Studio Beta 2.

Comment: This actually did fix it for me! Using 2.0 Preview 6...this just started randomly happening & clean - rebuild - run with some application restarts seemed to do nothing.

Comment: I had a similar problem. It just random started happening one day.

Comment: Got the error today after updating to AS 2.0. My version was already `1.20.1`, however, changing it to `'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'` fixed it for me.

Comment: According to the Fabric tutorial (https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html), it should be `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing the "apply fabric"

```
if (!devBuild) {
  apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}
```

So try to avoid not applying the fabric plugin.