# Can't release the project using crashlytics after upgrading to java 8

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After I move to `java 8`, I get this error in app release, because of `fabric` crashlytics:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease'.
> Task with path 'dexRelease' not found in project ':app'.
```

I'm using `Android Studio 2.2`, `Gradle version 2.14.1`, Android plugin version `2.2.0`

The project run without any problem, but I can't generate signed apk!

I read this post [Can't run project - Android Studio 2.0 Crashlytics issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921955/cant-run-project-android-studio-2-0-crashlytics-issues) and [Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug' if I enable the proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421193/could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appcrashlyticsstoredeobsdebug-i) but answer didn't helped me.

This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }

 dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
 }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
 compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "..."
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 17
    versionName "0.14.1"

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
  }

  signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("....jks")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
  }

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        shrinkResources true

        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug{
        debuggable true
        //applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
 }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

//Material edit text
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
//Circle progress bar
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.1.0'
//a divider for recyclerview
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.9'


//Field and method binding for Android views
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
//crash reporting and streamline solution for distributing apps
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar') {
      transitive = true;
   }

//LeakCanary
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'

compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile project(':core')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add multidex enable true to your gradle and clean the project

Comment: There seems to be some incompatibility between the gradle and fabri plugin. Avoid using '+' in the classpath for fabric. Use something like `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.1`

Comment: @ShrenikShah I enable multidex >>> `multiDexEnabled true` but it didn't help

Comment: @NarayanAcharya I changed classpath to  the latest version >>> `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'` but it didn't help

Comment: @HamedGh did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I check the fabric tools version from this link

https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Then I used a lower version `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'`